# Horizontal Scrollbar Not shown

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I'm try to show horizontal scroll bar. But instead of horizontal scroll bar it increases the height of div and if i change overfolw-x:scroll to overflow:scroll it shows me vertical scroll bar. Here below is the code. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <table style="width:800px; height:500px;border:1px solid black">
            <tr style="height:200px;border:1px dotted red;">
                <td>Test Text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:200px;border:1px dotted green;">
                <td>
                <div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow-x:scroll;">
                    Hello this is a testing text to make sure that the division overflow. 
                    Thanks for visiting. bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla blackbla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla blackbla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                    bla bla black bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 

                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is not advisable to include div inside td tag.....why don't you use div instead of table

Comment: Yeah you are right but this is sample code to identify the problem. Well thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give a fix `width` to the div.

I also used:

```
.cont{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

You can use `<br>` tag if you want to split the text into multiple lines:

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Mjuu/3/

Comment: Thanks abhijit for your solution. Yeah white-sapce did the trick in this case. This is sample code but in my actual code i have used repeater of image tag so there white space didn't works.

Comment: What do you mean by "repeater of image tag"? Can you update the code to replicate the issue?

Comment: If by repeater, you mean multiple img tags, Check the updated fiddle.

Comment: If by repeater, you mean multiple img tags, check the updated fiddle.